# Not getting updated error value from custom useAuth hook in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a custom useAuth hook that returns functions like signup, login and an error. But If there is an error such as wrong email and password, it doesn't return an updated error state variable in the Login.js and redirects the user to the /dashboard on form submit even if there is an error.

Login.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const { login, error } = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await login(user);
      navigate("/dashboard");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Log In</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input onChange={handleChange} type="email" name="email" id="email" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input
            onChange={handleChange}
            type="password"
            name="password"
            id="password"
          />
        </div>
        <button>Log In</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

useAuth.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { account } from "../appwrite/config";
import { ID } from "appwrite";

const useAuth = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const signup = async (user) => {
    try {
      await account.create(
        ID.unique(),
        user.email,
        user.password,
        user.username
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };

  const login = async (user) => {
    setError(null);
    try {
      await account.createEmailSession(user.email, user.password);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    try {
      await account.deleteSession("current");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };
  return { signup, login, logout, error };
};

export default useAuth;
```

Comment: Did you check `error.message` exists?

Comment: You're going to `navigate` to dashboard always because you catch the error inside `login`. Consider re-throwing after you set the error state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In of the `useAuth` functions, you need to throw the error inside the `catch` block so that the error is caught in `Login.js`. For example, try changing your `login` function to this:

```
const login = async (user) => {
  setError(null);
  try {
    await account.createEmailSession(user.email, user.password);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    setError(error.message);
    throw error; // Error that will be caught in Login.js
  }
};
```